# Integration in Simulink- output not as desired

Tags: simulink, integrator

I know this is fairly simply, am trying to achieve something as below to be implemented in Simulink:

i want the following:

out(i) = out(i-1) + abs(signal(i-1) - signal(i))*(time(i)-time(i-1));

This is what I have tried, I have no idea what went wrong.

I used the integrator block in the Matlab. But, the output I got is:

out(i) = signal(i)*(time(i)-time(i-1));

I understand that my signal and time will be in discrete rather than analog.

Appreciate any suggestion, thanks

Comment: You should be using Unit Delay blocks rather than Integrators if your signals are discrete time.

Comment: Dear Sir
 I have tried using the Unit Delay Blocks but still it didn't give the expected result. Where the inputs to Unit Delay Blocks are [0 1 2 3] for time and [5 5.1 5.2 5.2] for signal 
time   signal(desired output in bracket) 
0.0 20 (20)
1.0 5 (20.1)
2.0 5.1000 (20.2)
3.0 5.2000 (20.2)
Please see the image for better view: http://imgur.com/OpipALP

Comment: Assuming a sample time of 1s, then if the input signal is [5 5.1 5.2 5.2] then the output is expected to be [x0 5 5.1 5.1], where x0 is the initial state of the unit delay. Hence what you are getting is correct, and it is your expectation that is incorrect.